# Does this make sense as a way to implement role-based access control?

Tags: architecture, permissions, access-control, rbac

I've been developing a [user management system](http://www.userfrosting.com) which provides role-based access control for users.

### The way it currently works is as follows:

1. Authorization rules are specified which define specific checkpoints in the code where a user's permission needs to be checked.  This permission can be conditional, depending on the user's state and other variables.
2. Authorization rules are many-to-one mapped to what I have been calling "groups".  So, each group can have many rules, but rules cannot be shared by more than one group.  I realize now that my "groups" are what are more commonly referred to as "roles".
3. Users are many-to-many mapped to groups.  A user can belong to multiple groups, and a group can have multiple users.  Users inherit all the authorization rules of the groups to which they belong.
4. Users are also assigned to a single "primary group", which determines various other aspects of their experience like theming and layout, but can optionally be used as a condition in an authorization rule.
5. Users can also be directly assigned authorization rules, again as a one-to-many (user to rules) mapping.
6. The "master" account has unrestricted permission, automatically bypassing all checkpoints.

Graphically, this looks like:
[image: Old RBAC scheme]

### My new plan:

My plan is to bring it more into line with the standard terminology, and more cleanly separate the permission and user-experience aspects of group membership.  Thus, my new scheme would be:

1. Authorization rules are specified which define specific checkpoints in the code where a user's permission needs to be checked.  This permission can be conditional, depending on the user's state and other variables.
2. Authorization rules are many-to-one mapped to **roles**.  So, each **role** can have many rules, but rules cannot be shared by more than one **role**.
3. Users are many-to-one mapped to **groups**.  A group can have multiple users **but a user can only belong to one group**.  The group determines various other aspects of their experience like theming and layout, but can optionally be used as a condition in an authorization rule.
4. Roles can be many-to-many assigned to groups.  Users inherit all of the roles for the group to which they are assigned.
5. Users can also be directly assigned to roles, again as a **many-to-many** (user to roles) mapping.
6. The "master" account **automatically has all roles**.  However, the master account can still belong to a single group for the purpose of determining their theming and layout experience.

This would look like:

[image: New RBAC scheme]

My new scheme seems more complex because it introduces a fourth type of object.  On the other hand, it may be easier to work with because it more cleanly separates the "permissions" aspect of my system from the "group-based user experience" aspect.

Is this a sensible way to implement RBAC and user groups, or are there any weird edge cases I haven't considered?

Comment: You should look into existing RBAC implementations (Spring Security, Cancancan in Ruby, Slim in PHP...), or claims-based authorization (.NET) or better yet look into ABAC - attribute-based access control. ABAC will help you solve your access control issues

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I am basically implementing a form of ABAC.  However, I also have this extra piece of the puzzle - "groups" in addition to "roles", which I am looking for guidance with.